# If $f$ and $g$ are undifferentiable, can $f \cdot g$ be differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm making no progress on the question. I suspect the answer is no, but I have no evidence to back that claim.

Note that ... means I don't know what to do next

---

**Attempt 1**

$(f \cdot g)'(a) = f'(a) \cdot g(a) +  f(a) + g'(a)$

But neither $f'(a)$ nor $g'(a)$ exist

...

---

**Attempt 2**

Suppose so, i.e.

$\forall h \ (h \neq 0) \ \forall \epsilon \ \exists \delta \quad |h| < \delta \Rightarrow \left |\ \dfrac{f \cdot g \ (a + h) - f \cdot g \ (a)}{h} - l \ \right| < \epsilon$

...

Comment: Take $f$ invertible non-differentiable, and take $g = f^{-1}$ so that $f \cdot g = 1$ is of course differentiable.

Comment: Think about piecewise functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the product of two very "wild" functions can be quite "tame."

For example, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is *any function whatsoever*, and let $g(x)={1\over f(x)}$. Then $f\cdot g$ is the constant function $x\mapsto 1$, but we can whip up a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that both it and its reciprocal are as complicated as you want (e.g. nowhere continuous). (E.g. let $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and $2$ if $x$ is irrational.)

The situation here is basically the same as, but a bit more abstract than, the question "Can the sum of two irrational numbers be rational?" A very common theme in mathematics is:

> Combining two "nice" objects produces a "nice" object, but combining two "terrible" objects might produce anything whatsoever.

E.g. the sum of two rationals is rational but the sum of two irrationals could be irrational or rational, the composition of two continuous functions is continuous but the composition of two discontinuous functions could be discontinuous or continuous, etc.

Comment: Is composition being spoken of? Note that the product rule, rather than the chain rule is used in the attempt of the OP. Rest of the answer is fine!

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Whoops, misread - fixed!

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=g(x)=\begin{cases}
   1,&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
   -1,&x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

$f\text{ and } g$ are everywhere discontinuous and $fg$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f$ by 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \leq 0\\
  1, & x > 0.\end{cases}
$$
Certainly $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ since it is discontinuous there.  Now define $g$ as
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \leq 0\\
  0, & x > 0.\end{cases}
$$
Same story:  $g$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.  Yet, $fg$ is identically $0$, so it is fully differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Take 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }x\in \mathbb{Q}\\0\text{ if }x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}
$$
and $g(x)=1-f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be any non-differentiable function which doesn't take the value $0$ and put $g = 1/f$.

$f$ and $g$ are non-differentiable, and $f\cdot g\equiv 1$ is constant (so everywhere differentiable).